# Batch file to delete multiple values within a key in Registry

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, registry

The following key had multiple values like "Find", "Find 0", Find 1", "Find 2" and so on.
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Find

The values increase with use and I have no prior knowledge of the maximum number.
Goal is to create a batch file to delete all the "Find *" values without knowing the maximum value beforehand.

I tried the following with max number = 10:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,10) DO REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Find /v "Find %%G" /f
PAUSE
```

How do I loop till the max number if I don't have an idea about it?

I could put a large number like 100 and loop it through. But that would be unnecessary looping.

Idea:

After it reaches the max number it throws out an error in the console

```
"Error:  The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value"
```

I would like to capture this in a variable and check for the string "Error ...." and if true, terminate the loop.
I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to replace the FOR loop with the WHILE loop.

Of course, there's no such thing as 'the WHILE loop' in batch scripting. It is usually emulated with IF and GOTO.

Here's a sample script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET G=-1
SET Err=0
:loop
SET /A G+=1
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Find /v "Find %G%" /f || SET Err=1
IF %Err% == 0 GOTO loop
PAUSE
```

As you can see, the error is caught with the help of `||` operator. The command after `||` is only executed if the one before `||` resulted in an error. So, while the script is deleting values successfully, the `Err` variable remains unchanged, i.e. equal to 0, and so the subsequent IF always evaluates to TRUE and executes the GOTO accordingly.

As soon as there's an error when attempting to delete another value, the `SET Err=1` command is executed and, as a consequence, we are exiting the loop.

---

**EDIT** for the change request.

To account for the `Find` parameter (without numbers and spaces after the name) you'll have to act a bit differently, maybe like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET G=-1
SET Err=0
:loop
IF %G% == -1 (SET ParamName="Find") ELSE (SET ParamName="Find %G%")
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Find /v %ParamName% /f || SET Err=1
IF %Err% == 0 (SET /A G+=1 & GOTO loop)
PAUSE
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks a lot Andriy.

Comment: I have a few questions
1. "The command after || is only executed if the one before || resulted in an error." Is this statement true for all errors in any console command? I am confused because "REG DELETE" command has no return value.
2. There is also a value "Find" which does not have any trailing number. How would I delete that using the same goto loop?

Comment: @ontherocks: 1. It has to do with the so called *exit code*, which is returned by any application. It is not displayed, but can be checked 1) using the `IF ERRORLEVEL` instruction, 2) by reading the `ERRORLEVEL` environment variable, or 3) with the help of `&&` and `||` operators. You can read more about it [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php). 2. I added a modified solution, but normally you are supposed to post a new question. (Although your request is closely related to your initial question, it somewhat changes my original approach.) Please keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: is it posible do this in BAT, Powershell and Msbuild scripts ?

Comment: @alhambraeidos kiquenet: The above is a batch (BAT) script. As for the other tools mentioned, I *think* they allow you to implement anything you can implement in a batch script, but I won't be able to help you much there. You could post a question about it, though (and it would be better to post a separate one for each of the tools).